# Below ssh command sometimes not waiting for 60s till log file finishes its 60s, but it waits sometimes why?

Tags: linux, unix, command

**The command used though ssh:**

```
$ tac temp.csv | timeout 60s tail -f temp.csv | timeout 60s grep -w -m 1 'message' | awk '{print}' | tac
```

In above the command I want to search for a message in a log file, but after running this command, I would like to wait for 60 seconds, and then, after 60 seconds if the command found any result, return that result, or else return empty string.
But what I observed after running this command, is that sometimes this commands waits for 60 seconds, and sometimes it won't. Due to this behavior, I am facing a problem.

Can someone tell me why this kind of behavior, I am observing, occurs? Sometimes it waits for 60 seconds and sometimes not.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

```
tac temp.csv | (sleep 60; tail -f temp.csv) | timeout 60s grep -w -m 1 'message' | awk '{print}' | tac
```

**Full solution**

The 1st thing we should address is the proper usage of the `timeout` command.
As the man page says:

> timeout - run a command with a time limit ... Start COMMAND, and kill it if still running after DURATION.

It is not meant to be used as a pause button, rather a failsafe to "unstuck" an overly prolonged process. As opposed to that, the `sleep` command, is intended exactly for a time limited pause. From `sleep`'s man page:

> sleep - delay for a specified amount of time ... Pause for NUMBER seconds.

This brings us to the correct command, but now how to use this command? If we were to naively pipe to the `sleep` command we will lose the data piped to it. This can be seen like so:

```
echo "hello world" | rev | sleep 2 | rev
```

So looking at a [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325355/how-to-insert-a-delay-between-pipelining-commands-in-a-bash-script-e-g-cat-fil/19325515#19325515) we can see that running something like:

```
tac temp.csv | (sleep 60; tail -f temp.csv) | timeout 60s grep -w -m 1 'message' | awk '{print}' | tac
```

might work. However when using this solution you should take into consideration as to which of the commands in the parentheses will get the input piped into the parenthesised commands. As we have not used `tee` or some redirection trickery there is going to be only one input so commands such as:

```
echo "hello world" | rev | (tac; rev)
```

will only output `dlrow olleh`. So then we see that the 1st command that "expects" the input is the one to get it.